# IIS hosting, can't view site from my other machine on the same network

Tags: iis

I have a network setup containing two machines.

On one machine I have a site hosted with IIS. 
I have added an entry in the HOSTS file pointing my local IP to this domain 
10.42.12.105 to - www.mysite.come.  Then I configured to accept incoming calls on TCP Port 80. By going to windows firewall with advance security
Inbound Rules -> Action -> New Rule, select "Predefined" and then select the last item - World Wide Web Services(Http) and allow the connection. Also allowed port 80 too.

I can access the site with www.mysite.com with no problem on the same machine.
what I would like to do is be able to view this site from my other machine on the same network.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: 1. Did you add the entry in the HOSTS file of both machines?  2. What is the OS of the machine running IIS?

Comment: No I didn't add entry for both machines. Since it's going to be used by more than two machines. 
The OS is windows server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

A host file is a way to tell 1 machine to map a web address to an IP address, like an alias. It only works on the machine containing the HOSTS file. For example, I could add a line in my hosts file which could map your URL www.mysite.com to 127.0.0.1.  My browser would think your site is on my PC now.

So, if you want to set up this alias/name-mapping for multiple machines, you will need to add a host entry, on each machine (so they all have this mapping), or add this mapping to your local DNS (on your domain controller or router).

To check your firewall rules and IIS config, try having your test PC go to the IP address instead of the alias (from HOSTS).